# Efeito de escrita utilizando javascript, setInterval não funciona

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Estou tentando utilizar a função setInterval para escrever 1 letra a cada segundo, mas não funcionou:

```
partText = "";

function escrever(text) {   
    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        partText += (text.charAt(i));   
        document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = partText;
    }
}

setInterval(escrever("teste"), 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Erro está em duas parte:

**1 setInterval.**

> `setInterval(escrever("teste"), 1000);`

o correto é

> `setInterval(function(){escrever("teste")}, 1000);`

**2 Laço de repetição.**

> `for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++)`

Aqui ele sempre vai escrever tudo o que tem no text

Abaixo as alterações:

```
partText = "";
var index=-1;
function escrever(text) {   

    index++;

    if(index<text.length){    
      partText += (text.charAt(index));   
      document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML = partText;
    }  
    else
    {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }

  }

var timer= setInterval(function(){escrever("teste")}, 1000);
```

[Exemplo|jsfidlle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/e51963b8/)

Comment: Acho desnecessário ter uma variável global só para guardar o index do `.charAt` Nesse caso era bom ter uma variável para `document.getElementById("texto")`, assim evitando estar sempre a ir ao DOM buscá-la. Junta também `var` a `partText` para não exportar para o espaço global.

Answer (score 3):

Podes fazer assim:

```js
function escrever(text) {
    var el = document.getElementById("texto");
    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function(letra) {
            el.innerHTML += letra;
        }, 1000 * i, text[i]);
    }
}
escrever('teste');
```

```html
<div id="texto"></div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/y18afv4t/

A ter em conta:

- usa `+=` para acrescentar HTML. Somente `=` vai substituir tudo
- evita `document.getElementByID` dentro do `for`, isso é pesado para o browser. Coloca em cache como fiz no exemplo.

Answer (score 2):

O `setInterval` pode não ser uma boa, porque ele repete indefinidamente (até que seja determinado que ele pare com `clearInterval`).
O que recomendo é que utilize o `setTimeout` que executa apenas uma vez.

Com isso, seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
var partText = "";
function escreverNoObjeto (objeto, texto) {
    objeto.innerHTML = texto;
}

function escrever(text, intervalo) {
    var partText = '';
    var fn = function(texto) {
        return function() {
            /* pode ser document.getElementById("texto")*/
            escreverNoObjeto(document.body, texto);
        };
    };

    for (i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        partText += text.charAt(i);

        setTimeout(fn(partText), intervalo * (i + 1));
    }
}

escrever("teste", 1000);
```

Você ainda poder ver ele funcionando no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bcfnpdgo/)

Espero ter ajudado \o/

Comment: Estás a declarar `var partText = "";` duas vezes, acho que foi esquecimento não? Seria uma boa colcoar em cache o objeto do DOM fora de `fn` que é chamado n vezes.

Answer (score 1):

Os parametros não são passados assim como está a fazer:

Tente:

```
setInterval(escrever, 1000, 'test');
```

Exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4kz3e81/3/).

Não sei se é isso que quer mas assim a impressão de cada letra é instantanea, apenas na str toda é que se nota.

Para fazer letra a letra:

```
...
<p id="texto"></p>
...

var testStr = 'Vamos lá escrever isto';
function escrever(i) {
    partText = testStr.charAt(i);   
    document.getElementById("texto").innerHTML += partText;
    i += 1;
    if(i < testStr.length) {
        setTimeout(escrever, 400, i); // timing entre cada impressão aqui
    }
}

index_da_letra = 0;
escrever(index_da_letra);
```

Exemplo no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m4kz3e81/15/):

Comment: Essa função `escrever` é chamada eternamente... quando é que ela pára?